# Facing with invalid syntax during using a proposed python file

Tags: python, syntax-error, bz2

During using the below code which is available in [here](http://dynamomd.org/index.php/tutorialA#ExampleMakinganXYZPositionFile), the syntax error will occur to me and I don't know why! I guessed it's because I didn't install the mentioned library in code, but it isn't.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#A helpful function to load compressed or uncompressed XML files
def loadXMLFile("config.xml"):
    #Check if the file is compressed or not, and
    if (os.path.splitext("config.xml")[1][1:].strip() == "bz2"):
        import bz2
        f = bz2.BZ2File("output.bz2")
        doc = ET.parse(f)
        f.close()
        return doc
else:
        return ET.parse("config.xml")

#Load the XML file config.out.xml
XMLDoc=loadXMLFile("config.out.xml")

#We can create a list of all particle tags using an xpath expression
#(xpath expressions always return lists)
PtTags = XMLDoc.findall("//Pt")

#Print the number of particles
print len(PtTags)

#print the x, y, and z positions of each particle
for PtElement in PtTags:
    PosTag = PtElement.find("P")
    print PosTag.get("x"), PosTag.get("y"), PosTag.get("z"), PtElement.get("D")
```

Here is the orginal file in which there is "filename"

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#A helpful function to load compressed or uncompressed XML files
def loadXMLFile(filename):
    #Check if the file is compressed or not, and 
    if (os.path.splitext(filename)[1][1:].strip() == "bz2"):
        import bz2
        f = bz2.BZ2File(filename)
        doc = ET.parse(f)
        f.close()
        return doc
    else:
        return ET.parse(filename)

#Load the XML file config.out.xml
XMLDoc=loadXMLFile("config.out.xml")

#We can create a list of all particle tags using an xpath expression
#(xpath expressions always return lists)
PtTags = XMLDoc.findall("//Pt")

#Print the number of particles
print len(PtTags)

#print the x, y, and z positions of each particle
for PtElement in PtTags:
    PosTag = PtElement.find("P")
    print PosTag.get("x"), PosTag.get("y"), PosTag.get("z"), PtElement.get("D")
```

I don't know what is my mistake which I'm facing with this error? Is there any mistakes with directories? or perhaps some problems with file's name?

Comment: 'the syntax error' - which syntax error? If you don't post it, we can't guess...

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? Your `print` statements will only work in Python 2.

Comment: `loadXMLFile("config.xml")` is invalid syntax, so is your `else:` statement (due to lack of indentation)

Comment: @Barmar I use python3... What's the difference between print statement in Python 3 and Python 2? What should be exactly change?

Comment: In Python 3, `print` is a function, it needs parentheses around the arguments.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille When I run the script, the syntax error occur just before first "if", on def loadXMLFile(filename) ...and also on print len(PtTags).

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot sir... Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do your own edits. In the sample code, the `filename` is a parameter to the function, and should not be changed to a string. In the line where it says `XMLDoc=loadXMLFile("config.out.xml")`, the function is opening the file `"config.out.xml"` and using is as the `filename` parameter.

There's also problems with your else statement, but that's tied to not editing the function in the first place.

Try running the original code without your edits and see if any errors come up.

https://www.pythoncentral.io/fun-with-python-function-parameters/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The problem is when I leave the "filename" unchanged and run the code as you said without any modification, I faced with the same error.  I took a screenshot to show : https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501703268436

Comment: @AV That link doesn't work, I just see the Photobox home page.